# Make a blinking/flashing button on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, storyboard, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I'm trying to learn something about Storyboard and animations, so I decided to do a simple flashing button.

After some struggling I've been able to record the animation but it does not work as intended.

The animation is played once and it seems to ignore my `SpeedRatio` property.
I've even lost the `Pressed` animation!

Here's my code :

XAML

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="BPMFlashingButton.BPMFlashingButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BPMFlashingButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CustomStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Flashing">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button x:Name="FlashingButton" Content="Blink" Style="{StaticResource BPMFlashingButton}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneBorderBrush}"/>
```

Then I've got this method

```
public void startAnimation()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(FlashingButton, "Flashing", true);
    }
```

to make the animation start.

But when I call it, the button becomes Red and stays still, no flashing!

Any suggestion?

Comment: I can't test myself atm, but you can try to add an AutoReverse="True" to your ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.

Comment: Just tried, but it works as before :(

Comment: Have you tried adding another empty state to the CustomStates VSM group? I'm pretty sure VSM animates between two or more states in the same group and I'm not sure how it'll behave with only one state.

Comment: Still no success. I've tried with an empty state, then I've added some transitions between the blinking state and the empty one but stil no animations!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should record an independent Storyboard and not use VisualStateManager. You set the Storyboard to RepeatBehavior="Forever" and trigger it with a Trigger.